# How to find the categories of the emails given in "A subset of about 1700 labeled email messages" on UC Berkeley enron email analysis dataset?

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I was working with the dataset "A subset of about 1700 labeled email messages" from this website https://bailando.berkeley.edu/enron_email.html
But I am confused how to find the category of some email?

After extracting the file there are some email with xxxx.txt file and corresponding xxxx.cats file which contains the category of that email. and also there is also a categories.txt file containing how to find the category from the cats file.

like suppose there is a email on "3111.txt" file and it's category is given by the "3111.cats" file. But how I will find the category using the informations given in the file.
like in the 3111.cats file the given data is:

```
1,1,1
2,9,1
3,7,1
```

So what is the category of the file 3111.txt?

This is the info in the categories.txt file:

```
Format of each line in .cats file:
n1,n2,n3

n1 = top-level category
n2 = second-level category
n3 = frequency with which this category was assigned to this message


Here are the categories:


1 Coarse genre
 
1.1 Company Business, Strategy, etc. (elaborate in Section 3 [Topics])
1.2 Purely Personal
1.3 Personal but in professional context (e.g., it was good working with you)
1.4 Logistic Arrangements (meeting scheduling, technical support, etc)
1.5 Employment arrangements (job seeking, hiring, recommendations, etc)
1.6 Document editing/checking (collaboration)
1.7 Empty message (due to missing attachment)
1.8 Empty message


2 Included/forwarded information 

2.1 Includes new text in addition to forwarded material
2.2 Forwarded email(s) including replies
2.3 Business letter(s) / document(s)
2.4 News article(s)
2.5 Government / academic report(s)
2.6 Government action(s) (such as results of a hearing, etc)
2.7 Press release(s)
2.8 Legal documents (complaints, lawsuits, advice)
2.9 Pointers to url(s)
2.10 Newsletters
2.11 Jokes, humor (related to business)
2.12 Jokes, humor (unrelated to business)
2.13 Attachment(s) (assumed missing)


3 Primary topics (if coarse genre 1.1 is selected) 

3.1 regulations and regulators (includes price caps)
3.2 internal projects -- progress and strategy
3.3 company image -- current
3.4 company image -- changing / influencing
3.5 political influence / contributions / contacts
3.6 california energy crisis / california politics
3.7 internal company policy
3.8 internal company operations
3.9 alliances / partnerships
3.10 legal advice
3.11 talking points
3.12 meeting minutes
3.13 trip reports


4 Emotional tone (if not neutral) 

4.1 jubilation
4.2 hope / anticipation
4.3 humor
4.4 camaraderie
4.5 admiration
4.6 gratitude
4.7 friendship / affection
4.8 sympathy / support
4.9 sarcasm
4.10 secrecy / confidentiality
4.11 worry / anxiety
4.12 concern
4.13 competitiveness / aggressiveness
4.14 triumph / gloating
4.15 pride
4.16 anger / agitation
4.17 sadness / despair
4.18 shame
4.19 dislike / scorn
```

How to find the category of some email xxxx.txt file by the xxxx.cats file?